# Traversal of C string through pointer incrementation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c-strings

I'm reading through Bjarne Stroustrup's *A Tour of C++* and I'm having trouble understanding an early example. In the code below, a while loop is used to increment a pointer over a C style string until it hits the null character. What I don't get is why pointing to a null character would cause the pointer to take on the value of nullptr. It seems like it should be a perfectly good pointer that happens to point to a null value. I'd be surprised  if it were an author error since the book is included in stackexchange's reccommendations here: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

```
int count_x(char∗ p, char x)
    // count the number of occurrences of x in p[]
    // p is assumed to point to a zero-terminated array of char (or to nothing)
{
    if (p==nullptr) return 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (; p!=nullptr; ++p)
        if (∗p==x)
            ++count;
        return count;
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't; that code sample is wrong

Comment: The sample in the book is different. The loop is `while(*p)`. Which edition do you have?

Comment: Well, I have a version that I found by googling "*A Tour of C++* pdf" (first result). Serves me right I guess, although interestingly it purports to be copywrited 2014.

Comment: According to the [errata](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour_printing2.html), "The code for count_if() is wrong", in the 1st printing, fixed in the 2nd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check for null character, you should test `*p != '\0'`, not `p != nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

It segs for the reasons you mention. Try:

```
  for (; *p; ++p)
```